# How to compress an .avi video to 10% of its original size using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression

I have a video file that is 15 seconds in length and 465,195 KB. I would like to reduce it to somewhere around 46,000 KB. Is there an easy way to do this. I have tried the largest allowed bitrate

```
ffmpeg -i input -q:v 0 -b:v 900000k output
```

and I still get a file of only 3,500 KB

Thanks in advance

Comment: What codec are you using? `-q`'s meaning is codec-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

## How do I target a fixed file size using `ffmpeg`?

If you're willing to transcode using `x264`, you can follow the [encoding guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) which gives examples for how to target a particular file size.

```
target bitrate = target filesize / duration

ie     bitrate = 46000           / 15

ie     bitrate = 3067 (kbit / s)
```

You'll presumably need some of that for audio; the guide uses 128k as a rough default, so your target bitrate is **2939 kbit/s**. You can then use the *two-pass* encoding specification:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input -c:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v 2939k -pass 1 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -f mp4 /dev/null && \
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v 2939k -pass 2 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

> This method is generally used if you are targeting a specific output file size and output quality from frame to frame is of less importance.

You can of course tune this to your needs in terms of audio coded and so forth, but you should end up with a file of 46000kB.